# How to make puppeteer work with Firebase Functions (with latest puppeteer and node version 16)?

Tags: firebase, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a page using puppeteer, and the function crashes when called.
Here's my code:

index.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { scrapeWebsite } from "./core/scraping";

// // Start writing functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
exports.scrape = functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 120, memory: "2GB" })
  .region("us-central1")
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const stories = await scrapeWebsite();
    response.type("json").send(stories);
  });
```

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const scrapeWebsite = async () => {
  let stories: any = [];
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    timeout: 20000,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    slowMo: 0,
    args: [
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--no-first-run",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--no-zygote",
      "--window-size=1280,720",
    ],
  });

  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 });

    // Block images, videos, fonts from downloading
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    page.on("request", (interceptedRequest) => {
      const blockResources = ["script", "stylesheet", "image", "media", "font"];
      if (blockResources.includes(interceptedRequest.resourceType())) {
        interceptedRequest.abort();
      } else {
        interceptedRequest.continue();
      }
    });

    // Change the user agent of the scraper
    await page.setUserAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
    );

    await page.goto("https://www.nytimes.com/", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    });

    const storySelector = "section.story-wrapper h3";

    // Only get the top 10 headlines
    stories = await page.$$eval(storySelector, (divs: any) =>
      divs
        .slice(0, 10)
        .map(
          (div: HTMLElement, index: number) => `${index + 1}. ${div.innerText}`
        )
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }
  return stories;
};

export { scrapeWebsite };
```

Here's Google Cloud Logs for this function

```
Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1069273). This can occur if either
you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npm install) or
your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sysadm/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/var/www/html/oas-restapi-fork1/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:119:27)
at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/var/www/html/oas-restapi-fork1/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:205:25)
at ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/www/html/oas-restapi-fork1/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:93:37)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

I've been trying to use some existing methods to solve this problem, but they seem to be outdated (from 2018) and node version 8 is no longer supported by Firebase.